# Python decorator for function subsegments

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

In Python, is there a nice way to apply a decorator (or something similar) not to a whole function, but to a subsegment of a function body?

What I want might look something like this:

```
def deco_double(f):
    def wrapper():
            f()
            f()
    return wrapper

def foo():
    @deco_double:
        print("hello")
        print("stack")
    @deco_double:
        print("overflow")

foo()
```

So the execution result be like:

```
hello
stack
hello
stack
overflow
overflow
```

It's okay if the solution is not exactly a decorator, what I need is a method to wrap function subsegments, but in a well abstracted way. Thank you in advance :)

**edit:**
Just separating into multiple functions is not an option for me. I'm developing a framework for programmers and I want them to write functions in a compact way (for writing foo() in the example. Also, what I'm actually doing is far more complicated than just repetitions)

**edit2:**
By now it seems I have no choice but to expect framework users to somehow declare named functions...

Comment: Just use more functions.

Comment: You say separating into multiple functions is not an option, and then in the answer you accept you go ahead and do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function bodies are compiled into a single "code" object that is run as a whole - changing the way this code object is run, inserting things in it, and such are things that can be as complicated as the language code itself (i.e. the code that actually "executes" Python bytecode).

So, any changes in the flow of execution are far easier done by using the statements in the language that already do that.

If you want the equivalent of a generic decorator in parts inside a function body, the easiest thing to do is to subdivide that function itself into inner functions - and then you can apply your transforms, or execute each part more than once, by simply calling those functions (and even decorate them directly).

However, in the case you bring in your question, you could, and probably should, just use a plain old `for` loop:

```
def foo():
    for _ in (0, 1):
        print("hello")
        print("stack")
    for _ in (0, 1):
        print("overflow")
```

For arbitrary "decorator like behavior", as I wrote above, just use nested functions:

```
def foo():
    @deco_double
    def part1()
        print("hello")
        print("stack")
    part1()
    @deco_double:
    def part2():
        print("overflow")
    part2()
```

Comment: I appreciate your explanation about code execution of Python :) What I'm actually doing is much more than just loops. Being concise is a key for what I'm making (a framework), so I think lambda expressions better suits my requirements than nested functions.

Comment: Okay now I realize that there are no multi-line lambda expressions. I think this is a better option.

Comment: Also, the parttern normally used for this kind of stuff is the `with` statement and the Context Manager protocol. Although it can deal with a lot of things entering and leaving code blocks, it can't change that the code block is to be executed in order exactly once - that is why I did not mention it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extract that partial functionality of `foo()` to separate functions and then apply the decorator as a function and call it expilictly.

```
def deco_double(f):
    def wrapper():
            f()
            f()
    return wrapper

def my_f1():
     print("hello")
     print("stack")

def my_f2():
     print("overflow")

def foo():
    deco_double(my_f1)()
    deco_double(my_f2)()

foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to pass functions using `lambda` if you want to achieve this:

```
def doubler(f):
  f()
  f()

def foo():
  doubler(lambda: print("hello"))

  doubler(lambda: print("world"))

foo()
"hello"
"hello"
"world"
"world"
```

Wrap the code you want to be run twice in the `lambda`, and pass the function to `doubler`

Comment: I guess utilizing lambda expression was what I had to consider, thanks!!

Comment: They are often useful in generalizing code and reducing duplication.

Comment: I think it should be pointed out that this solution can also be used with normal functions and still be more concise than the other answers, as you don't need to think about naming the functions (`_` will do) and you don't have to call them separately.

Comment: Now I found that multiline lambda expressions are not possible... I think I can't use this if this is limited to just single line. Sorry

Comment: @Silvershine157 Yes. It's a very unfortunate limitation of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare two functions with any name with decorator `@deco_double` and call them in any other function, in your case `foo()` and then simply call `foo()`.

```
def deco_double(f):
    def wrapper():
            f()
            f()
    return wrapper
@deco_double
def func1():
     print("hello")
     print("stack")
@deco_double
def func2():
     print("overflow")
def foo():
    func1()
    func2()
foo()
```

Output of this code.

```
hello
stack
hello
stack
overflow
overflow
```